# Wires going to wall switch have no voltage but the outlet the switch controls has power

Tags: switch

In my Son's room, there is a switch on the wall that used to control one of the outlets across the room but stopped working long ago. I'm now finally getting around to trying to fix it. Ran a voltage test with multimeter directly on the wires and nothing. Yet somehow, the outlet it used to turn on and off is working.

The switch has 1 white, 1 black, and a ground wire.

Why would I have no juice in these wires, but there is in the outlet it used to control? Is this a bad breaker or bad wire?

Comment: There are a few possibilities of what is going on here. Pull out (but don't disconnect any wires) the switch and receptacle and take pictures showing how everything connects and upload them into your question

Comment: FIRST TURN OFF THE BREAKER and make sure the plug is dead. Then open switch and plugs, and carefully pull them out, slowly stretching the wires. If you are in north america, where we have dual receptacles, include pictures of both sides of the receptacle, the side with the white wire and the side with the black wire

Comment: Did it all work before you started work? If so they may have wired the neutral side by mistake it happens sometimes.

Comment: There may have been a problem with the wiring to the switch so someone abandoned the switch and installed a new receptacle with the "jumper" still intact on the new receptacle.

Comment: Which wires did you measure and how did you measure them?

Comment: not sure where my earlier response went but the wires coming from the outlet to the switch have no voltage so it's not the switch. At some point when my Son is not sleeping, I need to pull the outlet again and double check for any loose/disconnected wires. My gut tells me a wire that goes from the outlet to the switch may have come loose. Why else would there be no juice in the wires at the switch box?

Comment: Sounds like a common back stab or loose connection to me.

Comment: I checked both sides again. The outlet shows no signs of disconnect of wires. However, after resolving my other issue I learned a bit more about this process and I'm wondering how this could have ever worked and here's why:

1. From more research, my understanding is that a single pole switch just has two brass screws and the ground screw which is what I have.
2. There should be 2 black wires, one for the main line from breaker and other to the outlet or appliance.
3. But I only have 3 wires, a black, white, and ground. Is this normal? How would the switch power an outlet with 1 black wire

Comment: I just attached a diagram I found and it is pretty much exactly my setup except I have both sets of black/white wire for both outlets. I am baffled that it ever worked at all but  I know it did way back and I don't think I changed any thing but who knows? there is a ceiling fan switch a few inches to the right of this switch. it is a dimmer so no clue why they didn't split them out. I need to see if I can find a way to separate the fan switch from the fan light switch b/c now the dimmer just slows the fan down and dims the light at same time. I think I'm missing a set of wires.

Comment: How was your switch wired before you took it out?  Is it part of a 3 way , do you have another switch that controls this outlet as well?  Was black and white wired to the switch, are those wired in the same jacketing ? Are you sure about what it controls? Did someone change outlet . Did secondary set of wires get lost in wall ? Measure black to copper, white to copper and post what you measured.

Comment: I spent hrs today trying to figure this out to no avail. One thing I found though was that the two wires to the switch in question apparently are run through all outlets in the room. I know this b/c when I connected it to the line coming through the adjacent dimmer switch it controls all outlets in the room which we don't want. (breaker number 10) but then if I turn on breaker 14, it keeps the outlets on all the time regardless if it's connected to the # 10 line. Still no idea how this switch ever only controlled one outlet but we are certain it did.

Comment: And to add, there definitely was only one romex coming into the box for this switch and it most definitely goes to  the outlets since when connected to breaker line 10, it turns everything plugged into the outlets on and off. I think somehow there was one outlet perhaps connected to number 14 in such a way that it was the only one that could be shut off by the switch while all others are always on. I just can't wrap my head around this.